# convert space to newline - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have some data to a TextBox like this :

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
```

these words fetch from an other file, for some reasons i can't using `vbCrLf` - `vbCr` - `vbLf` - `vbNewLine` - etc

is it possible to convert spaces between words to a `vbCrLf` instead?
What I expect :

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

Comment: sorry @Plutonix modified

Comment: Is the first example what your input data looks like?

Comment: is ? or in ? @MarkHall

Comment: You could just use `String.Replace()` to change a single space to `Environment.NewLine` if that is exactly what it looks like.  of course, `a word` would get botched

Comment: Where/how are you reading the data. If  you are reading it from a file just use the [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: thanks, it worked @Plutonix ♥

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but if you are importing words form other files and you want a newline you want to do this :

```
    textBox1.Text = (code to import) & Enviroment.NewLine & etc...
```

So you can try that.

EDIT : Sorry, you can try this :

```
Dim txt As String = (code to import) & Enviroment.NewLine & etc..
```

Then you can do this :

```
textBox1.Text = txt
```

Comment: what is `Enviroment.NewLine` ??? i can do like this : `textBox1.Text = (code to import) & vbCrLf` but i can't do that as i saied

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, it's `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: no, i said that i can't use this way ! anyway your code is good. thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

thanks by [@Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix) :

As i expected, i can replace spaces by a newline

```
target = target.Replace(" ", Environment.NewLine)
TextBox1 = target
```